# Записать последние значение из mysql в переменную PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простенькая DB(id,link). Хочу взять последние значение из таблицы, конкретно поле link и записать его в href ссылки;

```
?php
  $servername = "";
  $database = "";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT link FROM smm ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $link = $row['link'];  
    echo "<p>$link</p>";
}
   mysql_close(); 
  ?>
  <a href="<?= $link ?>" >Link </a>
```

Comment: Пора понять что `mysql` и `mysqli` (__i__) это совершенно разные расширения.

Answer (score 1):

Если, как совершенно верно заметили в комментариях, вы разберетесь с расширениями mysql и mysqli (здесь советов не даю, т.к. зависит от версии PHP, которая у вас установлена), то останется только немного изменить запрос на: `SELECT link FROM smm ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Не помогло все равно, про расширение почитал, в моем случае они особо не влияют